# Show Log of a file in jgit when committng it as a BLOB

Tags: jgit

Implemented the above logic to create a new commit (with no parents) that contains only my file. Commits are fast in the repository as compared to `CommitCommand commit = git.commit();`

But I am not able to get the Logs of a particular file , the number of times it has been updated/revised , and every time i go for `Constants.HEAD` , I am getting null.

Any help will be of great advantage.

```
        Git git = jGitUtil.openRepo();
    Repository repository = git.getRepository();

    ObjectInserter repoInserter = repository.newObjectInserter();
    ObjectId commitId = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] fileBytes= FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(sourceFile);

        // Add a blob to the repository
        ObjectId blobId = repoInserter.insert(org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants.OBJ_BLOB, fileBytes);
        // Create a tree that contains the blob as file "hello.txt"
        TreeFormatter treeFormatter = new TreeFormatter();
        treeFormatter.append(actualFileName, FileMode.REGULAR_FILE, blobId);

        ObjectId treeId = treeFormatter.insertTo(repoInserter);

        System.out.println("File comment : " + relativePath + PortalConstants.FILESEPARATOR + actualFileName + PortalConstants.EP_DELIMETER + userComments);

        // Create a commit that contains this tree
        CommitBuilder commit = new CommitBuilder();
        PersonIdent ident = new PersonIdent(user.getFirstName(), user.getUserId());
        commit.setCommitter(ident);
        commit.setAuthor(ident);
        commit.setMessage(relativePath + PortalConstants.FILESEPARATOR + actualFileName + PortalConstants.EP_DELIMETER + userComments);
        commit.setTreeId(treeId);

        commitId = repoInserter.insert(commit);
        System.out.println(" commitId : " + commitId.getName());

        repoInserter.flush();
        System.out.println("Flush Done");
    }catch(IOException  ioe){
        log.logError(StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(ioe));
        System.out.println(StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(ioe));
    }
    finally
    {
        repoInserter.release();
    }
    return commitId.getName();
}
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, does any of the samples in my https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook help?

Comment: Hi Centic, thanks for your guidance. tried all the snippets fro the link posted by you . i continue to get no Head Exception . For better insight i am posting my commit code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [Add File](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/AddFile.java) and [Commit File](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CommitFile.java) porcelain commands instead of trying to implement it myself. Then retrieving the log should be possible via something like this:

```
    Iterable<RevCommit> logs = new Git(repository).log()
        .all()
        .call();
    for(RevCommit rev : logs) {
        System.out.println("Commit: " + rev + " " + rev.getName() + " " + rev.getId().getName());
    }
```

Where you can retrieve the additional information based on the commit-id.

I have now also added this as new snippet [Show Log](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are creating a commit with no parents, you are saying that there is no history. Therefore you won't be able to see any other changes from that history because it doesn't exist.

You probably should use a commit with the parent of the current position of the branch so that you'll be able to get more information.